# RxJava2 combine Observable<List<>> and Observable

Tags: rx-java2

I'm still learning RxJava 2, and I'm struggling to build an `Observable<List<>>` based on two Observables.

The goal is to build an `Observable<List<Schedule>>`.
I have the observables `Observable<List<Channel>> getChannels()` (= channel list) and `Observable<Schedule> getSchedule(long channelId)` (= schedule for a channel).

Here my current Observable, that is not emitting `onNext()`:

```
Observable<List<Schedule>> oSchedules = getChannels()
    .flatMapIterable(channel -> channel)
    .flatMap(c -> getSchedule(c.id()))
    .toList()
    .toObservable();

Observable<Schedule> getSchedule(long channelId) 
{
...
}

Observable<List<Channel>> getChannels() 
{
...
}
```

That is working fine, and emitting my data:

```
Observable<Schedule> oSchedule = getChannels()
        .flatMapIterable(d -> d)
        .flatMap(i -> getSchedule(i.id(), start, end));
```

### EDIT

The ToList() is only called onComplete of the Observable, that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: That's a reasonable way to do. What is the question?

Comment: @Héctor this is RxJava 2 where `toList` returns `Single`. If the OP wants it as `Observable` again, `.toObservable` is necessary.

Comment: Seems that getSchedule or getChannels is returning null

Comment: Mea Culpa, it's not working. However, when not calling toList, I have my item emitted...

Comment: @akarnokd the observable fails with the 'null mapper' error, I don't understand why, as without the toList, it emits the data, but as individual items (each observable works and doesn't return null, I tested with hardcoded value in each observable, same behaviour)

Comment: In each flatMap, place an `ObjectHelper.requireNonNull()` call with unique error message and see what is returning null.

Comment: @akarnokd I'm really lost now, when debugging step by step, I see the value of the object, but it's still giving me the error... Could link me to how to use the `ObjectHelper.requireNonNull()` properly?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. `.flatMapIterable(channel -> ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(channel, "channel is null"))
    .flatMap(c -> ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(getSchedule(c.id(), "Schedule is null: " + c.id()))`

Comment: @akarnokd I don't have any errorlog. I've put a log in getSchedule, and it goes in (I currently have only one element in getChannels for test purposes). It's like the toList() is never called...

Comment: @akarnokd Okaym so I gues I have my culprit: the observables are returned from SQLBrite mappers, and I think the toList() is not executed because the GetChannels() doesn't complete, and toList() needs this onComplete, no?

Comment: toList requires a finite source, many Android database tech uses infinite sources.

Comment: @akarnokd How can I emit a finite source from my DB inifite source?

Comment: I'm sure there are similar questions and answers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @akarnokd I think I'm too tired, I ended up by using a simple .take(1). Thank you for the exchange and the little kick in the backside :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToList() is only called onComplete of the Observable, that's why it wasn't working. Thanks to @akarnokd, this is what I ended up with.

```
    getChannels()
            .take(1)
            .flatMapIterable(c -> c)
            .flatMap(channel -> getSchedule(channel.id(), start, end)
                    .take(1))
            .toList()
            .toObservable()
```